# XML parsing program in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, parsing, xml

This is my code which works and compiles but I feel it may be non-optimal, especially the tag mapping and  use of the `if` command.

It reads two .xml files and finds what has been added or deleted on the new file. For new items it uses a map to link a tag name to a category of data (content tag is a description for example). This is important since different files have different naming conventions on the tags.

Finally, it does work on the data depending on its category (coming soon) and prints it.

```
#include "pugi/pugixml.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{

    std::string var;

    const std::map<std::string, std::string> tagMap {
        {"id", "id"}, {"description", "content"}, {"url", "web_address"}
    };

    pugi::xml_document doca, docb;
    std::map<std::string, pugi::xml_node> mapa, mapb;

    if (!doca.load_file("a.xml") || !docb.load_file("b.xml")) { 
        std::cout << "Can't find input files";
        return 1;
    }

    for (auto& node: doca.child("data").children("item")) {
    const char* id = node.child_value("id");
    mapa[id] = node;
    }

    for (auto& node: docb.child("data").children("item")) {
    const char* idcs = node.child_value("id");
        if (!mapa.erase(idcs)) {
        mapb[idcs] = node;
        }
    }

     for (auto& eb: mapb) {
        // Loop the tagMap, and try and associate the tag name to the content
         for (auto& kv : tagMap) {
             if (kv.first == "id") {
             std::string var = eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str());
             // Do work on returned value of id tag in the future (I.e validation)
             std::cout << var << endl;
             }
             if (kv.first == "description") {
             std::string var = eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str());
             // Do work on returned value of content tag in the future
             std::cout << var << endl;
             }
             if (kv.first == "url") {
             std::string var = eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str());
             // Do work on returned value of web_address tag in the future
             std::cout << var << endl;
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will only comment about the following not-fully-implemented part.

```
 for (auto& kv : tagMap) {
     if (kv.first == "id") {
     std::string var = eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str());
     // Do work on returned value of id tag in the future (I.e validation)
     std::cout << var << endl;
     }
     if (kv.first == "description") {
     std::string var = eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str());
     // Do work on returned value of content tag in the future
     std::cout << var << endl;
     }
     if (kv.first == "url") {
     std::string var = eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str());
     // Do work on returned value of web_address tag in the future
     std::cout << var << endl;
     }
 }
```

Even without much code filling the blanks, it seems that you want to have some associative `tag => function` data. In which case, you could create an `std::unordered_map` with strings as keys and associating function pointers to them, generated from captureless lambdas. A small example:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, void(*)(const std::string&)> tasks = {
    { "id", [](const std::string& val) {
        // Do work on returned value of id tag
    }},
    { "description", [](const std::string& val) {
        // Do work on returned value of content tag
    }},
    { "url", [](const std::string& val) {
        // Do work on returned value of web_address tag
    }}
};

for (auto& kv: tagMap) {
    auto it = tasks.find(kv.first);
    if (it != tasks.end()) {
        it->second(eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str()));
    }
}
```

That way, your code is easy to extend to other tags by representing tasks associated to tags as data and storing them into a map. Now, it will only work if you don't need captures, otherwise, you may have to use `std::function` or some more heavyweight mechanism instead of a big chain of `if`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Would you mind explaining what you mean by "need captures" please

Comment: @Jimmy A lambda capture corresponds to a variable in the body of a lambda that comes from the outer scope. For a C++ lambda `[](){}`, the capture corresponds to what is in the square brackets `[]`. A lambda with a capture cannot be converted to a function pointer.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain but within the "do work on id" bit how do I access the id, for example if I want to just print the id?

Comment: @Jimmy I guess that when `kv.first == "id"`, then the id you're referring to is `kv.second`, right? In this case, it will be fed to `it->second` which is the corresponding lambda, so the id would be the lambda `val` parameter.

Comment: thank you for the reply. In this case can I get the value with the code you posted above or is this the case where I would need the more heavyweight method like std::function. I'm just trying to get a description where I actually have access to what was found in the tag, so std::cout << it for example would print 1 (the id)

Comment: Its hard to describe but after I've done work on id/description etc I want to print it

Comment: @Jimmy If you copy the value before calling the lambda then make your lambda take a non-`const` reference, you may be able to print the altered `val` after the lambda was called (I hope I understood your question).